# react app on apache webserver changes depending on which git branch I'm on, can I have it point to main branch always?

Tags: reactjs, git, apache, github, branch

I currently have a react app that I've "deployed" by running `npm build`, and placing the files into the directory that apache2 points to as the virtualhost

The problem is, that the website that is displayed on the internet reflects whatever branch I check out. I'm currently logged in as root, and when I do `git checkout dev` on the server, the live website reflects the dev build instead of the version on the `main` branch

**I would like for the live site to always reflect the main branch, not whichever branch that the root user is on. How can I do this?**

This is my apache config

```
<VirtualHost {my_ip}>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot {path_to_react_build}
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

where `path_to_react_build` contains the built react app

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with the web server setup or anything, that is just what git  (or any other version control system) does: it changes the files such that they match the branch you checked out. If you check out some different branch than what you call the "main" branch, then you change the files present at the web server's document root. Thus that state of those files is what the web server delivers. That actually is the whole point of using a version control system.

Comment: In general you should _never_ perform development tasks on what you call the "live deployment", so inside the folder or system used to actually operate your web site. You should always have separate setups for development, test and production. Then ideally all you should ever do inside your production environment is a "pull" on your release branch.

Comment: The solution I came up with was to put the live site into a new directory that I added to gitignore, so that it stays the same regardless of which branch I'm on

Comment: And how are you going to update that?

Comment: I'm working directly on the server through ssh, so when I build the app and copy the files in the new, untracked directory, it will be updated there, right ?

Comment: What you actually _should_ do is that: you have one local clone of the repository in your local development environment. That is where you perform development. You make changes, test things, play around. Whenever some feature appears to be finished you commit and merge the changes. If you use a central repository you also push the changes. In another environment you have a repository clone to _test_ the current release. And in a third clone you have a _production_ version that is used by your http server. That way you simply perform a `git pull` inside your prod version to update. That's all.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, thank you for sharing this! Here is why I currently cannot that right now: 1. I don't want to use my local machine's resources to make changes and play around 2. I only have 1 server (can only afford 1 rn) so I can't have a testing environment

Comment: Then skip the test environment. But NEVER skip the separation of develop and production.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "use my local machine's resources"? What resources does an installed by disabled http server use? None (except of a few MB of installed binaries).

Comment: I mean if you don't have a development environment and do not want to invest into a second hosted environment (which I absolutely agree on), then how do you even test changes you implement? _On the production environment? Really?_

Comment: You also generally should not do development *as* the super user (`root`).